# Redis pub/sub востановление пропущеных сообщений

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Есть провайдер и получатель. Между ними редис в качестве брокера сообщений. Получатель это отдельный сервис, который может отваливаться. И в момент когда он поднимаеться он должен вывести все пропущеные сообщения. Как это пожно устроить.

Есть 2 варианта которые пришли мне в голову.
1 Возможно есть какой то способ буферезировать все сообщения средствами редиса
2 отправлять в качестве сообщение в системе pub/sub тип list и в провайдере добавлять сообщение и в получателе удалять его из листа. Может кто подскажет можно ли так или направит на более рабочий вариант

Comment: Так pub/sub или очередь ? Да, вы можете класть сообщение через LPUSH и забирать RPOP или даже RPOPLPUSH если боитесь что процесс обработчик может упасть и ему надо будет повторно прочитать потерянное при сбое

Comment: Мне один из двух вариантов. Главное что если сообщение было отослано в момент когда получатель не работает то он смог после востановления вывести все пропущенное. Не предпологаеться что сервер может упасть по время обработки

Comment: тогда да, лист. сервер будет хранить все что добавили пока не заберут